# Laravel 5 routes call controller directly

Tags: php, laravel, controller, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I'm trying to call a controller directly in routes.php in Laravel 5 like this:

```
    Route::get('/', function()
{

    if (\Auth::guest()){
        $controller = new \App\Http\Controllers\ConstructorController;
    }else{
        $controller = new \App\Http\Controllers\HomeController;
    }

    return $controller->index();
});
```

However, I get the following error:

> FatalErrorException in routes.php line 109: Class 'HomeController' not
>   found

What is it that I'm missing?

Thanks

Comment: The HomeController? :) Do you have a HomeController class defined in \App\Http\Controllers namespace?

Comment: Based on what you are doing in your example, you may be better off using middleware http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/middleware

Comment: As suggested.. it is better to use middleware here. It is much easier to implement and understand

Comment: I think your namespance is set to be App\Http\Controllers in RouteServiceProvider inside app\Providers folder.

Comment: You should check the namespace and make the object removing the path till namespace.

Answer (score 0):

try to do a `composer dump-autoload`